# Mongo docker container stops at SHARDING, and the container is not successfully created

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to start a mongo docker container with docker-compose, it worked for my first two tries and now I cannot make it work anymore, anytime I try to run:

```
docker-compose up
```

The execution stops at this line:

```
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:42:00.000+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mondodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: PasswordOfTheRoot
      MONGODB_INITDB_DATABASE: exampledb
      MONGODB_NON_ROOT_USERNAME: tidra
      MONGODB_NON_ROOT_PASSWORD: tidra
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

Here is the whole execution:

```
Recreating microservices-test_mondodb_container_1 ... done                                                                                                         Attaching to microservices-test_mondodb_container_1
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.498+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.504+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=017a4a41dad8
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.504+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.505+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*" } }
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.506+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.506+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten]
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.506+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.506+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:33.506+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=482M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.389+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1583556454:389436][1:0x7fb169ed1b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 19
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.454+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1583556454:454638][1:0x7fb169ed1b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 19 through 19
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.556+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1583556454:556820][1:0x7fb169ed1b00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 18/6272 to 19/256
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.687+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1583556454:687007][1:0x7fb169ed1b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 19
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.795+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1583556454:795297][1:0x7fb169ed1b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 19 through 19
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.861+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1583556454:861429][1:0x7fb169ed1b00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.914+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.920+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.925+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.926+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.926+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.926+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.929+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.932+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.932+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.932+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.935+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.935+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.937+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.937+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.937+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.937+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:34.938+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
mondodb_container_1  | 2020-03-07T04:47:35.000+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
```

I am running on:

```
OS: Windows 10
Docker: v19.03.5, build 633a0ea
```

I have tried:

```
    ->Mongo container v4.2
    ->Mongo container v4.0
    ->Restarting Docker 
    ->Change the TCP port
```

I saw an open ticket about this at the MongoDB website, however they said this was resolved on the v4 of mongo.

Does anyone know how can I overcome such issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this too and it was driving me crazy!

The good news is that it's actually working. The output you're seeing are just logs and that's the last log message. If you open up a new terminal and do:

```
docker ps -a
```

then you should see that container running. You can then do:

```
docker exec -it [the container name] bash
```

You'll be in the container and can run `mongo -u root -p` to actually connect to mongo.